# Screw Terminal Block Amperage Ratings

Tags: amperage, component-selection, screw-terminal

Does the 15A amperage rating for screw terminal blocks such as the ones shown below refer to each pole or to the entire product?

I have a project that will require 5A on each pole. Would this block work for me?

[image: 5 Pcs 600V 15A 6 Positions 2 Rows Barrier Screw Terminal Block Strip w Cover]

Comment: These types of connectors are new ~ 5 mOhm or 75mW loss @ 15A with correct torque, so this sounds right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 15 A rating is the current capability across each bus connection and on each terminal. So you can't use two terminals to take 30 A in and ferry it to two further-down terminals to take that 30 A out.

Your description sounds like you want to take a single supply in and route out several 5 A supplies out. You can bring in several 15 A supplies, each on its own wire and near three terminals loading with 5 A. Even though these will all be connected to the same common bus-bar, distributing the supplies and loads that way will be fine. (I designed a similar arrangement recently, routing out 40 A to a variety of loads.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am, in fact going to route several 5 A supplies out from a common bus created from tying one side of the barrier together. Now I just need to find a strip to connect them that is rated to 30 A.

Comment: @joe, glad it helped, good luck with it and thanks for the upvote on the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If not otherwise stated on the datasheet then it is per pole for any or all poles in use. It's possible some terminal blocks might have a derating under some conditions.

So, check the datasheet. The molded in numbers should not be depended on.

In my opinion, 5A is certainly okay **if** that terminal block is made from safe materials in the first place, **however** I don't see any safety agency markings so it may not be all that safe.